# What can I use instead of gtk_container_set_focus_chain()?

Tags: gtk, gtk3

The [gtk_container_set_focus_chain()](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/method.Container.set_focus_chain.html) function deprecated since GTK 3.24. What can I use instead of?

Answer (score 2):

The link you provided indicates:

> Deprecated since: 3.24
>
> For overriding focus behavior, use the GtkWidgetClass::focus signal.

which, of course, is [almost fully undocumented](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/signal.Widget.focus.html) (sigh). I have checked the demos and saw nothing related to this, sadly.

From this [migration from GTK3 to GTK4 guide](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/migrating-3to4.html#adapt-to-gtkcontainer-removal):

> In GTK 4, any widget can have children (and `GtkContainer` is gone).
> There is new API to navigate the widget tree, for use in widget
> implementations: `gtk_widget_get_first_child()`,
> `gtk_widget_get_last_child()`, `gtk_widget_get_next_sibling()`,
> `gtk_widget_get_prev_sibling()`.

This could be a good place to start.